# buscar por tipo no funciona

Tags: php, mysql

Hola gente tengo la siguiente aplicación web en php

(catalogo.php)

```
<body class="homepage">

        <?php require_once('cabecera.php'); ?>

        <!--Container cabecera-->
        <section id="feature">  
            <div class="container">
                <div id="titulo-cabecera">Articulos</div>
                <!--<p>Eleg&iacute; el articulo</p> -->


        <!--Fin Container cabecera-->

        <!--Comienzo container buscadores y ofertas-->


            <div class="row" id="buscadores">
                <!--<div class="col-md-4-fluid">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="buscarnombre.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Buscar por nombre">
                             <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                             </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            -->
                <div class="col-md-4-fluid">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="buscartipo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="pull-right">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Buscar por tipo</option>
                                <option value="tecnologia">Llave T</option>
                                <option value="deportes">Herramientas especiales</option>
                                <option value="arte">Kit de puesta a punto</option>
                                <option value="viajes">Otros</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                             </span> 
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--Fin row buscadores-->

            <!--Comienzo row ofertas-->

        <div class="row" id="catalogo"> 
                <?php
                include "conexion.php";

                            if(isset($_SESSION['empleado'])){
                                $idempleado=$_SESSION['empleado']['id_usuario'];
                                $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM empleado where id_usuario!='$id_usuario'");
                                while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="thumbnail">
                                            <a class="example-image-link" href='<?php echo($array['imagen']);?>' data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Optional caption."><img class="example-image" src='<?php echo ($array['imagen']);?>' alt=""/></a>
                                            <div class="caption">
                                                <p><?php echo $array['descripcion'];?></p>
                                                <h3><?php echo "$".$array['precio'];?></h3>
                                                <?php echo "<p><a href='descripcion.php?id_plantilla=$array[id_plantilla]' class='btn btn-primary' role='button'>Comprar ahora</a></p>";?> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }else{
                            $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM articulo");
                            while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                                ?>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <a class="example-image-link" href='<?php echo($array['imagen']);?>' data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Optional caption."><img class="example-image" src='<?php echo ($array['imagen']);?>' alt=""/></a>
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p><?php echo $array['codarticulo'];?></p> 
                                            <h3><?php echo "$".$array['precio'];?></h3>
                                           <?php echo "<p><a href='descripcion.php?idarticulo=$array[idarticulo]' class='btn btn-primary' role='button'>Ver detalle</a></p>";?> 
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>              

            <!--Fin row ofertas-->
        </div>
        </div>
```

quiero que cuando selecciono en el combo Buscar por tipo, alguna de las opciones solamente queden los artículos de dicha categoria. que estoy haciendo mal?  (buscarportipo.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $tipo=$_POST['tipo'];

    if(empty($tipo)){
        echo "<script>alert('Seleccione un tipo de plantilla')</script>";
        echo "<script>location.href='catalogo.php'</script>";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Inicio | F y F herramientas</title>
        <!-- core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

         <!-- para sweet alert2 -->
        <script src="bower_components/es6-promise/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script> <!-- for IE support -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
</head>
    <body class="homepage">
        <?php require_once('cabecera.php'); ?>      

        <section id="feature">
            <div class="container">
            <!--Container cabecera-->

                <div class="container" id="contenido-cabecera">
                    <div id="titulo-cabecera">Articulos</div>
                    <p>Filtrado por tipo</p>
                </div>

            <!--Fin Container cabecera-->

            <!--Comienzo container buscar por tipo-->           
                <div class="row" id="buscar-tipo">  
                    <?php
                    include "conexion.php";

                    /*$id_articulo=$_SESSION['articulo']['idarticulo'];          */ 
                    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM articulo where tipo='$tipo'");
                    while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                        if(['idarticulo']!=$id_articulo){
                    ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a class="example-image-link" href='<?php echo($array['imagen']);?>' data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Optional caption."><img class="example-image" src='<?php echo($array['imagen']);?>' alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <p><?php echo $array['descripcion'];?></p>
                                    <h3><?php echo "$".$array['precio'];?></h3>
                                    <?php echo "<p><a href='descripcion.php?id_plantilla=$array[id_plantilla]' class='btn btn-primary' role='button'>Comprar ahora</a> </p>";?> 
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    <?php
                        }

                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!--Fin container buscar por tipo-->
        </section>  
    <?php require_once('pie.php'); ?> 
</html>
```

diseño de bd

```
CREATE TABLE `articulo` (
  `idarticulo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codarticulo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `precio` double NOT NULL,
  `imagen` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idarticulo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: algún error que te arroja?

Comment: no, simplemente no me duveluve nada

Answer (score 0):

```
if(['idarticulo']!=$id_articulo){
```

Tiene toda la pinta de que la línea anterior debería ser:

```
if($array['idarticulo']!=$id_articulo){
```

---

**EDITO**

Aparentemente la variable `$id_articulo` no está definida en ese fichero, luego el `if` lo deberías eliminar pues tu intención es mostrar todos los artículos para una categoría dada.

Comment: no me funciona sigue sin funcionar, no me devuelve nada

Comment: como haria el if?

Comment: @user1851950 el `if` solo tiene sentido si quieres filtrar parte de los resultados... Aunque lo mismo podrías conseguir metiendo más filtros en la consulta...

Comment: Es lo que hago. Si le saco el if me hace lo mismo

Comment: @user1851950 ¿y que significa "_me hace lo mismo_"? Si al quitar el `if` no te aparecen resultados entonces hay otro problema en el código.

Comment: Vos que me recomendas? No me esta saliendo

Comment: me hace lo mismo quiere decir que cuando selecciono un tipo, no me devuelve nada

Comment: @user1851950 prueba a imprimir la query y ejecutala manualmente con phpmyadmin o similar. Lo mismo los tipos están mal definidos en el formulario

Comment: probè eso y la query me anda bien y los tipos están bien